# Win 7 64Bit Laptop; Should I Reinstall Windows Firewall

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

For some unknown reason, I can no longer enable network discovery in the control panel when the Windows Firewall is enabled. I tried restoring the Windows Firewall defaults and that did not work. As soon as I disabled the Windows Firewall, network discovery enabled itself automatically. Should I reinstall Windows Firewall? If yes, how do I reinstall it?

Answer (score 0):

There is no explicit way to reinstall the windows firewall. You may want to run `sfc /scannow` with admin privileges to see if that helps.

If you absolutely need to use Windows Firewall then you may have to reinstall the OS.

However, Windows firewall isn't that good of a firewall and is riddled with holes. You'd be better off using Comodo Firewall instead.

Answer (score 0):

1. control panel - admin tools - services - right click "ssdp discovery" - properties - auto
2. "upnp device host" and do the same,
3. restart windows and try to enable network discovery

or

1. control panel - advanced security - windows firewall - "Restore Default Policy"

or

1. Export firewall polices from computer without this problem.  (control panel - advanced security - windows firewall - ...)
2. Copy the .wfw file you exported to your computer.
3. Use the "import Policy" option in Windows Firewall on your computer

If it's not helped, may be you has installed other firewall?